# jquery function contain not work wiht .on() function

Tags: jquery, ajax

every things in this code is working but the browser cant  apply the jquery function after import the new content

html code :

```
<div class="id2" >  </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div> <br/>
```

the link

```
                 <div class="read">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table" width="100%">



            </table>
            </div>
```

jquery code :  this  code
have 2 function first function  insert to the database and import new content 
         the second function its will delete from database  and  hide tr from table that deleted 
           the problem the user cant delete from table when this content its import from the first function ,, jquery function not work

/*** delet and hide  ****/

```
    $(document).on("click", "#backup", function(){        // when  click 'the link'  this will import new content and update databace  and i use .on() function for it
  var s = {
      "id": "backup_tables"
        };
  $.ajax({         // here will do some thing in databacse
      url : "function.php",
      type : "POST",
      data :s,
      success : function (data){
         $(".id2").stop().stop().html(data).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);    // here the massges for user will set in the class "id2"
      },
  });

      var s = {
      "id": "backup_readlast"
        };

  $.ajax({    // hrer will add new content
      url : "function.php",
      type : "POST",
      data :s,
      success : function (data){
      $(".read table tr:last").after(data);       // here will set the new content in the end of table and it's  working ,
      $("#table tr:last").hide().fadeIn(800);      // but The problem that the import content is not applies jquery code
      },
      beforeSend : function (){

       $(".id2").html("<img scr =\"../images/loading.gif\"  alt=\"\" />");

      }
});
return false;
});
      /*** delet and hide  ****/
 $(".backupdelete").click(function(){   // here this function must be work after import new content  ,, but desn't work
           var name = $(this).attr("title");
           var s = {
      "id": "backupdelete",
      "id2" : name
        };
  $.ajax({
      url : "function.php",
      type : "POST",
      data :s,
      success : function (data){
         $(".id2").stop().stop().html(data).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);  // here the massges for user will set in the class "id2"
      },
      beforeSend : function (){
       $(".id2").html("<img scr =\"../images/loading.gif\"  alt=\"\" />");
      }
  });
$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(500);
return false;
});
```

Comment: What Jquery version are you using? Are you getting any error in Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, use on() in every cases :

```
  /*** delet and hide  ****/
  $('body').on('click',".backupdelete",function () { // here this function must be work after import new content  ,, but desn't work
      var name = $(this).attr("title");
      var s = {
          "id": "backupdelete",
              "id2": name
      };
      $.ajax({
          url: "function.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: s,
          success: function (data) {
              $(".id2").stop().stop().html(data).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500); // here the massges for user will set in the class "id2"
          },
          beforeSend: function () {
              $(".id2").html("<img scr =\"../images/loading.gif\"  alt=\"\" />");
          }
      });
      $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(500);
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: thank you  >> this problem  take a  long time >> its working now